# Any closed subspace of a compact space is compact - George Simmons proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

There are a couple of different proofs for this theorem but I wanted some clarification on Simmons' version. The proof goes: Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a compact space $X$, and let $\{G_i\}$ be an open cover of $Y$. Each $G_i$, being open in the relative topology on Y, is the intersection with $Y$ of an open subset $H_i$ of X. Since Y is closed, the class composed of $Y'$ and all $H_i$'s is an open cover of $X$, and since $X$ is compact, this open cover has open subcover. If $Y'$ occurs in this subcover, we discard it. What remains is a finite class of $H_i$'s whose union contains X. Our conclusion that Y is compact now follows from the fact that the corresponding $G_i$'s form a finite subcover of the original open cover of Y.

I agree with most of the proof except the part: "If $Y'$ occurs in this subcover, we discard it. What remains is a finite class of $H_i$'s whose union contains X." Can anybody clarify those statements or show why they are true or necessary?

It appears that the conclusion of the proof does not require those statements because if we have (by compactness of $X$) $$H_1\cup...\cup H_n\cup Y'=X$$ then $(H_1\cap Y)\cup...\cup (H_n\cap Y)=Y$ follows immediately by applying intersection with $Y$ and hence Y is compact.

Comment: I'll agree that the statement isn't totally necessary, but the author is making a relation between $H_i$ and $G_i$, since the goal is to find a finite subcover of $\{G_i\}$. So for clarity the author does not include $Y \cap Y' = \emptyset$, since $\emptyset$ is not necessarily in $\{G_i\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. do you think that the statement "What remains is a finite class of $H_i$'s whose union contains $X$" is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your understanding of the situation is very good, but there's a technical reason the proof is written this way.

We begin with an open cover $\{G_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $Y$, and we aim to produce a finite subcover.

Eventually, we find an open cover $\{H_1, \dots, H_n, Y'\}$ of $X$. It is true that then $\{H_1 \cap Y, \dots, H_n \cap Y, Y' \cap Y\}$ is an open cover of $Y$, but it is not necessarily a *subcover* of $\{G_i\}_{i \in I}$, because it contains $Y' \cap Y = \varnothing$ (while the empty set may not be present in $\{G_i\}_{i \in I}$). To fix this, we simply remove $Y'$ from the cover, if it was present.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It makes sense to remove $Y'$ to find an appropriate finite subcover for $\{G_i\}$ but I am not sure why "the finite class of $H_i$'s whose union contains $X$"

Comment: Oh yikes, this seems to be an error in the text! The union of the $H_i$'s need not be all of $X$. The author meant to say "whose union contains $Y$". Does this help? Apologies for not catching this earlier.

Comment: I thought so too but did not have the guts. Thank you very much !